# Swift: Using Int in UILabel inside View Controller

Tags: swift, xcode

I've set up an if statement which does things depending on an int value stored in a UILabel, however, my code can't determine the value of the int inside the label.

This is because the if statement runs within the viewdidload function. I'm basically looking for how I can pass the label value to my view. I'm struggling to make it work.

Here's the code:

```
   override func viewDidLoad()
   {
        // If statement
        var NumberRead = Int(Number.text!)

        if NumberRead! <= 2 {
              Picture.image = Pic1
        } else {
              Picture.image = Pic2
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var Number: UILabel!
```

Any suggestions for better ways to handle this would be amazing.

Thanks

Comment: How about having the code that assigns the value to the label update the picture's image as well?  You could put that code into a method so that they are always updated together.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is that you use this code in viewDidLoad, but that your UILabel is empty when you run the code and the code is unwrapping a nil value. You have to set the UILabel Number to a value before you use the if statement.

I don't know what value you expect in the Number label, but either set it with an initial value, e.g. 0, or when this view controller is called through segueing from another view controller pass on the value the label should have. The code should then work fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about:
set the default image to pic2, then use optional binding to check the value

```
Picture.image = Pic2
if let numTxt = Number.text {
    if let num = Int(numTxt) {
        if num <= 2 {
            Picture.image = Pic1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your data and logic from the view. It is absurd to put a value into a label and try to interpret it. Please consider reading up on the MVC (model view controller) pattern which is the underpinning of iOS.

Your view controller should have a variable, say `number` to keep track of the value that determines which image to show.

```
var number: Int = 0 {
    didSet { 
        imageView.image = number <= 2 ? pic1 : pic2
        label.text = "\(number)"
    }
}
```

---

#### On naming

Your variable names are also a mess. By convention variables are `lowerCamelCase`. If you are naming an `UIImageView`, the name `picture` is too generic and could be misleading. Also avoid names like `pic1`, `pic2`, better is something like `activeImage`, `inactiveImage`.